# Creating 450px x 450px PNG with ImageMagick for various sized images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, imagemagick, irfanview

I have a mixture of e-commerce product images that are various widths and heights but with a max of 400px.

As I am having issues with uneven product listings, I want to use ImageMagick to bulk resize them into 450px x 450px images.

Can this be done in the CLI using ImageMagick or perhaps Irfanview? I have tried with Irfanview, but cannot see any way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried RIOT Tool(radical image optimization tool)? you can check this application to do batch processing. I haven't tried ImageMagick but from past, I am using RIOT for batch processing. It works well.

**Link:** http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/

For Batch processing : **tools->batch optimizer->additional tasks->compress to size/flip/resize/rotate->add_image** or you can checkout the documentation on the site itself.